# No connection string named 'KgSoftProContext' could be found in the application config file

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've added the DLL in my project database. main sentence even though the connection in the config file add it to the project I'm getting this error.

Database dll App.Config file

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Main Project app.config file

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="KgSoftProContext" connectionString="Data Source=KDRGNY\KDRGNY;Initial Catalog=KgSoftPro;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

context file

```
 static KgSoftProContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<KgSoftProContext>(null);
        }

        public KgSoftProContext()
            : base("name=KgSoftProContext")
        {
        }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it's been outta control I'm trying to do the problem completely. the problem is solved.

Answer (score -2):

copy the connections string section to the .config file in your main project.

Comment: copy the connections string section to the .config file in your main project.

Comment: @rory.ap -- the second paragraph of the main project code belong to.